# Copying lib dependencies using gulp-npm-dist

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm working on a project that I'm copying lib from `node_modules` to my `dist` using `gulp-npm-dist`.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var npmDist = require('gulp-npm-dist');

gulp.task('copy:libs', function() {
  gulp.src(npmDist(), {base:'node_modules'})
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/vendor'));
});
```

[image]

I have successfully copied the required dependencies to dist/vendor and I thought I could reference them in my index.html

`<script src="../../vendor/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>`

But it is not to be as I'm getting an error of
Cannot GET /vendor/bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.min.js

May I ask what am I missing here? Any pointers is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you forget /dist directory in your path, in your screenshot bootstrap-select.min.js is in bootstrap-select/dist

```
<script src="../../vendor/bootstrap-select/**dist**/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```